# How do I pass arguments to a self-executing module.exported anonymous node function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to call a self-executing anonymous function exported with module.exports with a parameters object from another nodejs file by requiring the file with the anonymous function and passing the parameters object like this:

**fileThatCallsTheAnonymousSelfExecutingFunction:** 
`

```
var parameters = {
    filename: "UsernamesAndQueues",
    headers: ["username", "password", "queue"],
    columns: ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"],
    wordLength: 25,
    count: 100
};

var generateData = require("../scripts/generateData.js")(parameters);
```

**generateData.js:**

```
// if the function does not call itself in this file, i can pass the
// arguments normally, and it prints out the expected options.

module.exports = (function (options) {

    console.log("Hello %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    options = options || { 
                            "headers": ["username", "password", "queueName"], 
                            "columns": ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"], 
                            "wordLength": 26, 
                            "count": 101
                        };

    console.log("Current options are: %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    // I just want to know what the arguments are for now, so I interrupt
    process.exit();
    // i just want for the moment to print out the options object
    // later on, i would like to use the options as i would parse arguments ??? options[0], options[1], options[2] etc. 

    // rest of the file that really needs the function arguments 
    console.log("something");
    var fs = require('fs'),
        generate = require('csv-generate'),
        filename = "UsernamesAndQueues",
        csvfilestream = fs.createWriteStream("../data/" + "generated" + filename + ".csv", { flags: 'w' }),
        error = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/node.error.log', {flags: 'w'}),
        // CSV generator (read command line arguments, create with defaults, making filename required)
        generator = generate({
            header: options.headers, 
            columns: options.columns,
            max_word_length: options.wordLength,
            length: options.count
        });

        // Redirect stdout / stderr to file
        process.stdout.write = csvfilestream.write.bind(csvfilestream);
        process.stderr.write = error.write.bind(error);

        // Handle Uncaught Exceptions / Errors
        process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
            console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err);
        });

        // Output CSV to stdout stream -> to file
        generator.pipe(process.stdout);
})(arguments[0]);
```

I'm asking what is the correct way of handling the arguments passed to the function ? I want to do it this way in order to call it from cmd line, as well, with (optional) command line arguments. After I figure out how to do it this way, I can use an argument parser, further.

If you have other suggestions of implementing a node script (function) that can run as a command line script (`node generateData.js --headers ["param1", "param2", "param3"] --columns ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"] --wordLength 25 --count 100` and as a required the module exported function file into another one and passing a parameter object like above (`var generateData = require("../scripts/generateData.js")(parameters);` ), please do write a witty response!

Other questions: what am i doing right, what am i doing wrong, what and where can I read to better grasp these concepts? I've looked on Mozilla Dev and some other sites. I've found things regarding self-executing anonymous functions with parameters, but none called from an external file. Maybe I'm not even searching for the right thing...

Later edit:
I have already tried exporting the function and calling it from another file. This is the easy way.

**scriptThatRequiresTheExportedModuleAndCallsItWithParameters(Arguments).js**

```
var parameters = {
  headers: ["username", "password", "queue"],
  columns: ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"],
  word_length: 25,
  count: 100
};
// this works
var generateUsernames = require('../scripts/generateData.js')(parameters);
```

**generateData.js**

```
// this works, just exporting the function, without self-executing (calling)
// i call the function (providing arguments) from the other file requiring it
module.exports = function (options) {
    console.log("Hello %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    options = options || { 
                            "headers": ["username", "password", "queueName"], 
                            "columns": ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"], 
                            "wordLength": 26, 
                            "count": 101
                        };
    console.log("Current options are: %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    // exiting, because, for now, i just want to know what the arguments (options) are
    process.exit();
    console.log("something");
    var fs = require('fs'),
        generate = require('csv-generate'),
        filename = "UsernamesAndQueues",
        csvfilestream = fs.createWriteStream("../data/" + "generated" + filename + ".csv", { flags: 'w' }),
        error = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/node.error.log', {flags: 'w'}),

    // CSV generator (read command line arguments, create with defaults, making filename required)
    generator = generate({
        header: options.headers, 
        columns: options.columns,
        max_word_length: options.wordLength,
        length: options.count
    });

    // Redirect stdout / stderr to file
    process.stdout.write = csvfilestream.write.bind(csvfilestream);
    process.stderr.write = error.write.bind(error);

    // Handle Uncaught Exceptions / Errors
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
        console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err);
    });

    // Output CSV to stdout stream -> to file
    generator.pipe(process.stdout);
};
```

Comment: And nit-picking: It's not *self-executing*, it's just inline-invoked. The colloquial term for it is IIFE (inline-invoked function expression).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought it meant *immediately*-invoked function expression.

Comment: @torazaburo: I've heard both, but yours is the one I prefer and meant to use. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jfriend00 pointed out, "... [your code] executes immediately, not later when somebody who uses your module decides to call it." You need to assign the function to `module.exports` for `require` to use it in the expected way.

To get the "command line with node generateData.js [list of arguments]" behavior you're looking for, you can add a conditional that checks if the context is CLI, and then invoke the function, or export if not:

```
var fancyFn = function(options) {
  ...
};
if (require.main === module) {
  fancyFn(arguments[0]);
} else {
  module.exports = fancyFn;
}
```

Comment: [From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module): *When a file is run directly from Node.js, require.main is set to its module.* However, I recommend you consider @jfriend00's answer. Keeping this kind of logic in your module file will lead to keeping this kind of logic in all of your module files. Yes, you *could* do this. You probably *shouldn't*, though.

Comment: Yes, this might be a possibility, I guess. Although, this resembles the _pythonic_ way of doing things. What is the require.main property? Where could I read about this, to not bother you more with extra explanations?

I will try the above way and example, and come back to thank you (I'm already knowing that this will work out and that I'll come back to mark the answer :-") 

In the first branch of the conditional, I can even parse the cmd line arguments and show a help menu, then build the _options_ object and call the fancyFn.

Comment: Can you think of a repercussion of using this kind of approach in the long term? (one file per module, argument parsing for each one; instead of using one file per module and command line util in another file)

Comment: Nothing specific off the top of my head. This approach smells funny; it wouldn't be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and it wouldn't be [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), and there be dragons in the ocean.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the proper structure.  Self executing (which is technically "inline invoked") executes immediately, not later when somebody who uses your module decides to call it.  It appears you just want to export a regular function and don't need the self executing part at all.  Then, the caller of your module will supply the arguments as your usage pattern shows.

Just change to this:

```
module.exports = function (options) {

    console.log("Hello %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    options = options || { 
                            "headers": ["username", "password", "queueName"], 
                            "columns": ["ascii", "ascii", "ascii"], 
                            "wordLength": 26, 
                            "count": 101
                        };

    console.log("Current options are: %s", JSON.stringify(options));
    process.exit();
    // i just want for the moment to print out the options object
    // later on, i would like to use the options as i would parse arguments ??? options[0], options[1], options[2] etc. 

    // rest of the file that really needs the function arguments 
    console.log("something");
    var fs = require('fs'),
        generate = require('csv-generate'),
        filename = "UsernamesAndQueues",
        csvfilestream = fs.createWriteStream("../data/" + "generated" + filename + ".csv", { flags: 'w' }),
        error = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/node.error.log', {flags: 'w'}),
        // CSV generator (read command line arguments, create with defaults, making filename required)
        generator = generate({
            header: options.headers, 
            columns: options.columns,
            max_word_length: options.wordLength,
            length: options.count
        });

        // Redirect stdout / stderr to file
        process.stdout.write = csvfilestream.write.bind(csvfilestream);
        process.stderr.write = error.write.bind(error);

        // Handle Uncaught Exceptions / Errors
        process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
            console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err);
        });

        // Output CSV to stdout stream -> to file
        generator.pipe(process.stdout);
};
```

P.S. Why do you have a `process.exit();` in the middle of your function which renders the rest of it unused?

---

If you want to be able to use this from the command line or as a regular module that someone else calls, then you can make another small module that fetches the command line arguments, loads this module and calls it.  It isn't clear to me exactly how you want the command line arguments to work, but the general structure would be this:

```
// command line module processing module
// gendata.js

// load the generateData module
var gData = require('./generateData.js');

var options = {};
// some code here to process the command line arguments in process.argv
// into the options object

// call the other module with the command line arguments in the options object
gData(options);
```

Then, you can execute this from the command line:

```
node gendata.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: I want the function to execute in command line with node generateData.js [list of arguments] and by requiring the file (module) in another node script var generateData = require('generateData.js')(arguments). I already stated in the first comment of the generateData.js that I know and tried the version you pointed out. I'm looking for a double usage way of calling the function. 
How would you execute this function as a script in the command line? without entering node environment per se: as node generateData.js [options]?

Comment: @brainsearching - Command line arguments are in `process.argv`.  A given module has to know whether it is being asked to process command line arguments or just be a module for someone else to call.  I would suggest you make a small module that does the command line stuff and loads this module.  I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: Good call on separating the responsibility of CLI magic from module magic.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want the cmd line args to work, because I want to write some automated tests. In case I want to first run the data generation script, before I even load the test file, I want to be able to tell my test runner to run this generateData script with some arguments, or if I want to run it manually from command line, while developing the tests. I can see where your _modularize, modularize, modularize_ paradigm is going :) Thanks for the eye opening and will wait for your example to better understand and grasp it!

Comment: What about @user866762 way of doing things?

Comment: @brainsearching - Feel free to go that way.  It's not my preference.  If I were to implement that scheme, I would use it for a module self test (a common thing in python programming), not for implementing command line functionality.

Comment: @jfriend00 When are you going to post that fine example ? I'm really curious about the correct way of doing things.

Comment: @brainsearching - It's at the end of my answer for the last 10 hrs.  I'm not sure what you were looking for.  I was just showing how you use a small module that handles the command line parsing, organizes the command line arguments into your options object, loads the main module and then calls the main function just like any other user of the module would.  I can't show any detail with the command line arguments because you don't offer any specifics for what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks a bunch for your time and help!

Comment: @jfriend00 Adding this as a response to the question, for code cleanliness and modularization, despite of the file overhead and possible confusion between scripts and modules' names.